# Extract 7 bits signed integer from u8 byte

Tags: rust, byte, endianness

I am using the Human Interface Device protocol to get data from an external device. The library I'm using returns an array of bytes (`[u8; 64]`) which I want to extract an `i7` (which will be `i8` in Rust) from one byte.

The byte I want to manipulate has two different pieces of information in it:

- 1 bit for something
- the 7 other bits (which I have to decode as a signed integer) for another thing.

Do you know what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. For example, showing us the input values and the desired output values would go a **long way**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [the crate `bitreader`](https://crates.io/crates/bitreader) I have been able to properly decode the signed integer of 7 bits.

```
let mut bit_reader = BitReader::new(buffer);
let first_useless_bit: u8 = bit_reader.read_u8(1).unwrap();
let extracted_value: i8 = bit_reader.read_i8(7).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is pretty unclear, but I think you are just asking about normal bit manipulation. Mask the 7 bits (assuming the *lower* 7 bits, although you did not say) and convert the remaining bits to a signed number:

```
fn main() {
    let byte = 0xFFu8;
    let byte2 = (byte & 0b0111_1111) as i8;
    println!("{}", byte2);
}
```

Comment: Not working. I have been able to make it work with the following library https://crates.io/crates/bitreader.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn an array of `u8` into a vector of `i8` while ignoring the most significant bit, you can do it in the following manner:

```
fn main() {
    let array_unsigned = [1u8, 2, 3]; // this will work for 64 values too
    let vec_signed: Vec<i8> = array_unsigned.into_iter()
        .map(|&e| if e <= 127 { e as i8 } else { (e - 128) as i8 }).collect();

    println!("{:?}", vec_signed);
}
```

This way consumes the input array. It could probably be done in a nicer way with some bit-fiddling.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for but thank you for your help though :) I really want to fetch 7 bits from a simple byte (u8) and decode it as a signed integer.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess I forgot to mention something. The byte I want to manipulate has two different informations in it. 1 bit for a first information and the 7 other bits are for another information. So yes your solution would work if the whole byte contained only one information.

Comment: @craigzour how about now? This way should discard the information contained in the most significant bit.

Comment: I tested it even though I knew it was not going to work (and it is not). The way a signed integer is expressed at a byte level makes it impossible to decode using your solution. I think I just found a library which should help me: https://crates.io/crates/bitreader